# What’s the word to describe someone who works somewhere, but not always?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, business-language

I’ve been racking my brain about this for a solid 30 minutes and I keep drawing blanks. I know there’s a specific word for someone who works at an establishment, but doesn’t work a consistent schedule. It’s not “part-timer” “floater” “Standby” or “On-call”. There’s a specific term for it, like you’d ask someone:

P1: “What days do you usually work?”

P2: “I only come in when they need extra help.”

P1: “Oh, so you’re a ____?”

Comment: Why does "part-timer" not work?

Comment: “On call” best fits the example sentence..

Comment: [Supernumerary?](https://www.publicpeople.org/what-is-a-supernumerary.htm)

Comment: P2 : Yes, I am a [temp](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/temp).

Comment: Are you looking for PRN? It means as needed. In the medical fields, like nursing, this term is used frequently. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prn

Answer (score 3):

You can say **"I am a casual"**.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/casual) has

> **casual**
> <sub>*noun*</sub>
>
> a worker who is not employed permanently but only when a company needs them

Comment: This is in the written title of some jobs

Comment: A recent term in UK is "zero hours contract".

Comment: That doesn’t sound like American English — not my version, anyway.

Comment: @TinfoilHat the Q is not tagged for American English dialect.

Answer (score 2):

**[freelance](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/freelance)**

*adjective, adverb*

doing particular pieces of work for different organizations, rather than working all the time for a single organization:

- Most of the journalists I know are/work freelance.
- a freelance artist

Comment: freelanc**er** i.e. independent contractor

Answer (score 1):

chwilliamslaw.com

"What Is Per Diem Employment?

Per diem employees do not have regular schedules and instead provide availability hours. They work those hours if their employer has a need for them. Instead of being paid at an hourly or salaried rate, per diem employees are paid on a per diem rate, which is often a higher rate."

Answer (score 0):

Would it be the [itinerant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/itinerant) worker?

M-W gives:

> traveling from place to place especially
> : covering a circuit.
>
> *itinerant preacher*

Comment: That implies travelling about looking for casual work, not working occasionally for the same company.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer would be a **locum**. A locum doctor acts like a supply teacher does in schools, arriving to support other staff as and when needed.